# fluentd in_tail plugin pos_file content format

Tags: fluentd

I'm using fluentd to tail log files and and push the logs to an elastic search index. I have two questions -

1) How does fluentd store the position it last read into for a given file?
An example in my pos file is -

```
/myfolder/myfile.log     00000000004cfccb        0000000000116ce0
```

What do the values `00000000004cfccb` and `0000000000116ce0` denote?

2) This particular file (`myfile.log`) has 2520 lines in total. For some reason the last 100 lines were not read. I restarted the td agent but it still failed to read the last 100 lines. When can that happen?

My td-agent source looks something like this -

```
<source>
  type tail
  format none
  path /myfolder/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/mylogfiles.pos
  tag mylog.*
  read_from_head true
</source>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

For 1, see this comment: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/5ed4b29ebda0815edb7bdd444e7e5ca2e9874a27/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb#L652.
Hex number of position in the file and inode of the file.

For 2, putting events into file is also 2420 lines?
You can check the problem is in_tail or out_elasticsearch with below.

```
<match mylog.*>
  type copy
  <store>
    type file
  </store>
  <store>
    type elasticsearch
  </store>
</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)
pos_file /var/log/td-agent/mylogfiles.pos

above parameter is highly recommended. Fluentd will record the position it last read into this file. When ever you restart the td-agent it read the file of last index i.e (mylogfiles.pos internaly generated following values for ex: 00000000004cfccb and 0000000000116ce0 these values can changed whenever td-agent restart )

2) 
Please follow the below URL
https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_tail#read_lines_limit

read_from_head true remove and try once

Answer (score -1):

From fluentd docs

> The regexp for the format parameter can be specified. If the parameter
>   value starts and ends with “/”, it is considered to be a regexp. The
>   regexp must have at least one named capture (?PATTERN). If the
>   regexp has a capture named ‘time’, it is used as the time of the
>   event. You can specify the time format using the time_format
>   parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that answers any of my two questions. The format attribute seems to be related to the format of the log content in the log file being read which could be used to parse the log content. I'm referring to the content of the pos file.